# Identify the Meeting Request cancel request?

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm writing an add-in (in C# and Outlook 2010) to validate some fields in the New Meeting Request - for example, that a meeting can not be more than 1 hour (I just show a message box).

I use the Application_ItemSend() method to identify the send item. There, for example, I check the Start and the End time of the meeting. The problem is after the meeting request has been sent - and I want to cancel it - when I click on Send Cancel the message box appear and tell me that the meeting is more than 1 hour.

How can I identify the meeting request type? for example, if this is a new meeting request or a Cancel meeting request?

---

I found the answer... It should be:

```
if (meeting.MeetingStatus == Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeetingCanceled) return;
```

The data is saved in: Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeetingCanceled

Sorry.

Comment: I found the answer... It should be:

if (meeting.MeetingStatus == Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeetingCanceled)
                    return;

Comment: I found the answer... It should be:

if (meeting.MeetingStatus == Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeetingCanceled)
                    return;

Comment: Why not show the failing code in your question, then write an answer and show the code that works. That will help others with the same problem. You should then accept your own answer and get points.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer... It should be:

```
if (meeting.MeetingStatus == Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeetingCanceled) return;
The data is saved in: Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeetingCanceled
```

Comment: MeetingItem in Outlook didn't have definition for MeetingStatus